# Saving value as a variable name in database

Tags: php, mysql, variables

Database Table **company_info**

```
-----------------------------
| companyname | companytype |
-----------------------------
| Company One | Blah        |
-----------------------------
| Company Two | Blah2       |
-----------------------------
```

Database Table **invoice_template**

```
-----------------------------
| Header      | bgcolor     |
-----------------------------
| $company    | Red         |
-----------------------------
| $company    | Biege       |
-----------------------------
```

PHP file **common_include.php**

```
$company = ... //FROM db table company_info field companyname
```

PHP file **invoice.php**

```
include('common_include.php');
$header = ... //FROM db table invoice_template field header
echo "Header is ". $header;
echo "<br/>Company is ". $company; //$company is defined in common_include.php
```

**OUTPUT of invoice.php** when company logged in is for eg.Company One

```
Header is $company
Company is Company One
```

Question: How do I get the $company in the output to be shown as Company one? i.e How do I get the output from MySQL DB to be treated as a variable?

Comment: What's the deal with the line `$header = FROM db...` because that should be invalid PHP...

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat . $header = FROM db .. is not valid php, it just means I am pulling data from db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution would be `eval("echo $header")`, although you should NEVER EVER want to resort to such solutions. You should -in my opinion- move all company related data into the database.

**Update**
You shouldn't put `$company` in your database. Relational databases should be **relational**. That means, primary keys and foreign keys. Data should then be looked up by it's relation. See also how an ORM would work in this situation:

```
echo $invoice_template->getCompany()->getName();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't understand why I shouldn't do this? The company data is in the db. the file only populates it into variables , so that the app can access it with an include. Is that risky? Please explain.

Comment: and echo eval($header) may work but, doesn't work in my setup. because that variable and others are in a variable, used to display the invoice as pdf. eg. The real string is like $pdfcontent = <<<EOF html...<h1>$header</h1>...more html EOF; . and I am using TCPDF. The output I now get is eval($comapny)

Comment: As I still discourage you to go this path, it would be something like `$company = 'My Company'; $which = '$company'; eval("\$which = $which;"); echo $which;`

Comment: I am thinking about redesigning my db/code, instead of doing it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to do this. You're just opening up too many potential vulnerabilities mixing code and data like that - just imagine what happens when an attacker gains access to your database (either directly or through SQL injection) and puts all sorts of crazy PHP code into that column? Using just a single vulnerability like this, an attacker might be able to take over the entire server.
What you want is probably a combination of a proper database structure, using joins to query for related information in one go, and maybe a simple text search-and-replace (using `str_replace` or maybe even `preg_replace`) to fill text templates with actual data.

Comment: Thanks. I could replace $company with a pseudo variable like #company and then preg_replace #company with the current company name.

Comment: You can use `$company` as well, just don't feed it to `eval()` or similarly evil constructs. Also, `str_replace()` does the job faster than `preg_replace()`, as long as you don't need anything fancy.

Answer (score 1):

If `$header` is set to the literal string value `$company` and the variable `$company` is set to the string `Company One` then this should work:

```
echo "Header is ". $$header; // outputs 'Header is Company One'
```

However, as others have said, this is not a good idea, particularly for security.

Comment: As I agree this idea is also an ugly idea, it wouldn't like this. $header should then be set to the literal string value `company`. Otherwise php throws a notice: 'Undefined variable $company'. This should work: `$header = substr($header,1); $header=$$header; echo $header;`. Still, this is as ugly as `eval()`.